# Python(Bottle)で作成したWEBアプリで結果が表示できない

Tags: python, python3, django, flask, bottle

Python初心者です。
Pythonで作成したプログラム（簡単な計算/mahjongライブラリ）をbottleフレームワークを使用してWEBブラウザに表示したいと考えています。

※一部修正しました

### 実行環境

Python3.8以上
bottle 0.12.19
mahjong  1.1.11

### ディレクトリ

project
　├views
│   ├index.html
　│ └mahjong.html
　└main.py

"localhost:8080/"に表示されているサブミットを押下したら、"localhost:8080/mahjong"のページ移動するようにしていますが、main.pyで実行している計算結果（print_hand_result(result)）がNoneと表示されてしまっています。（main.py）を実行したあと、起動するIDLEには計算結果が表示されています。

ブラウザ上にresultのみを表示した場合は結果が表示されるので、print_hand_resultが表示できていないことまでは分かっています。

（print_hand_result(result)）を表示できるようにしたいのですが、どのようにしたらよいでしょうか。
ご教授お願い致します。

### 発生しているエラー

```
Bottle v0.12.19 server starting up (using WSGIRefServer())...
Listening on http://localhost:8080/
Hit Ctrl-C to quit.


Warning (from warnings module):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 914
ImportWarning: _ImportRedirect.find_spec() not found; falling back to find_module()
```

### ソースコード

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from bottle import route, run, template,view

import mahjong
import os
import cgi
import sys
import io

@route('/')
def index():
     return template('index.html')

#計算
from mahjong.hand_calculating.hand import HandCalculator
#麻雀牌
from mahjong.tile import TilesConverter
#役, オプションルール
from mahjong.hand_calculating.hand_config import HandConfig, OptionalRules
#鳴き
from mahjong.meld import Meld
#風(場&自)
from mahjong.constants import EAST, SOUTH, WEST, NORTH

#HandCalculator(計算用クラス)のインスタンスを生成
calculator = HandCalculator()

#結果出力用
def print_hand_result(hand_result):
     #翻数, 符数
     print(hand_result.han, hand_result.fu)
     #点数(ツモアガリの場合[左：親失点, 右:子失点], ロンアガリの場合[左:放銃者失点, 右:0])
     print(hand_result.cost['main'], result.cost['additional'])
     #役
     print(hand_result.yaku)
     #符数の詳細
     for fu_item in hand_result.fu_details:
          print(fu_item)
     print('')

#アガリ形(honors=1:東, 2:南, 3:西, 4:北, 5:白, 6:發, 7:中)
tiles = TilesConverter.string_to_136_array(man='677889', pin='88', sou='456', honors='222')

#アガリ牌(マンズの8)
win_tile = TilesConverter.string_to_136_array(man='8')[0]

#鳴き(なし)
melds = None

54#ドラ(表示牌,裏ドラ)
dora_indicators = [
    TilesConverter.string_to_136_array(pin='7')[0],
    TilesConverter.string_to_136_array(sou='9')[0],
]

#オプション(リーチ, 自風, 場風)
config = HandConfig(is_riichi=True, player_wind=SOUTH, round_wind=EAST)

#計算
result = calculator.estimate_hand_value(tiles, win_tile,melds,dora_indicators, config)

@route('/mahjong',method=["GET","POST"])
def mahjong():
     a=print_hand_result(result)
     return template('mahjong.html',mahjong=a)
      
if __name__ == "__main__":
     run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True)
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="jp">
<html>
<head>
　 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
　</head>
<body>
  <center><br><br>
  <form action="/mahjong" method="POST">
    <h1><font color="#FF7F50">麻雀点数計算</font></h1><br /><br />
　　　<input type="submit" value="結果を表示" />
  </form>
  </center>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="jp">
<html>
<head>
　 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
　</head>
<body>
  <center><br><br>
     <h1><font color="#FF7F50">麻雀点数計算</font></h1><br /><br />
　  </form>
    <p>
    結果は<br /><br />　
    {{ mahjong }}
    </p>
  </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

[`print`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/functions.html#print)関数はコンソールに文字列を表示するだけなので、`print_hand_result`が値を返さないため変数`a`が空っぽなのが端的な理由です。
[関数](https://docs.python.org/ja/3.7/reference/compound_stmts.html#function)から値を返すには`return`を使ってください。

なお`result`変数自体が表示するデータを保持しているので、関数内で文字列を整形するのではなくテンプレートエンジンの[Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/)などを使って、テンプレートで直接変数を展開することをお勧めします。

下記のサンプルコードは、`result`変数を`get_hand_result`関数で出力文字列に加工して返す方法と、`mahjong.html`で直接表示する方法です。
実行には`pip install jinja2`などでパッケージをインストールしておく必要があります。

**サンプルコード**

pythonファイル

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from bottle import route, run, view
from bottle import jinja2_template as template

import mahjong
import os
import cgi
import sys
import io

@route('/')
def index():
     return template('index.html')

#計算
from mahjong.hand_calculating.hand import HandCalculator
#麻雀牌
from mahjong.tile import TilesConverter
#役, オプションルール
from mahjong.hand_calculating.hand_config import HandConfig, OptionalRules
#鳴き
from mahjong.meld import Meld
#風(場&自)
from mahjong.constants import EAST, SOUTH, WEST, NORTH

#HandCalculator(計算用クラス)のインスタンスを生成
calculator = HandCalculator()

#結果出力用
def print_hand_result(hand_result):
     #翻数, 符数
     print(hand_result.han, hand_result.fu)
     #点数(ツモアガリの場合[左：親失点, 右:子失点], ロンアガリの場合[左:放銃者失点, 右:0])
     print(hand_result.cost['main'], result.cost['additional'])
     #役
     print(hand_result.yaku)
     #符数の詳細
     for fu_item in hand_result.fu_details:
          print(fu_item)
     print('')

#結果を文字列として戻す
def get_hand_result(hand_result):
     lines = []
     #翻数, 符数
     lines.append("{}翻 {}符".format(hand_result.han, hand_result.fu))
     #点数(ツモアガリの場合[左：親失点, 右:子失点], ロンアガリの場合[左:放銃者失点, 右:0])
     lines.append("失点1:{} 失点2:{}".format(hand_result.cost['main'], result.cost['additional']))
     #役
     yaku_names = [y.name for y in hand_result.yaku]
     lines.append("役: {}".format(", ".join(yaku_names)))
     #符数の詳細
     for fu_item in hand_result.fu_details:
          lines.append(str(fu_item))
     lines.append('')
     print(lines)
     return lines

#アガリ形(honors=1:東, 2:南, 3:西, 4:北, 5:白, 6:發, 7:中)
tiles = TilesConverter.string_to_136_array(man='677889', pin='88', sou='456', honors='222')

#アガリ牌(マンズの8)
win_tile = TilesConverter.string_to_136_array(man='8')[0]

#鳴き(なし)
melds = None

54#ドラ(表示牌,裏ドラ)
dora_indicators = [
    TilesConverter.string_to_136_array(pin='7')[0],
    TilesConverter.string_to_136_array(sou='9')[0],
]

#オプション(リーチ, 自風, 場風)
config = HandConfig(is_riichi=True, player_wind=SOUTH, round_wind=EAST)

#計算
result = calculator.estimate_hand_value(tiles, win_tile,melds,dora_indicators, config)

@route('/mahjong',method=["GET","POST"])
def mahjong():
     a=get_hand_result(result)
     print(a)
     t=['a','b']
     return template('mahjong.html', mj=result, is_tsumo=config.is_tsumo, lines=a)
      
if __name__ == "__main__":
     run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True, reloader=True)
```

mahjong.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="jp">
<html>
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
  </head>
<body>
  <center><br><br>
     <h1><font color="#FF7F50">麻雀点数計算</font></h1><br /><br />
    </form>
    <p>
    結果は<br />文字列なら…<br />
    {% for line in lines %}
        {{line}}<br/>
    {% endfor %}
    </p>
    <p>
    結果は<br />mahjongインスタンスなら…<br />
    {{mj.han}}翻 {{mj.fu}}符<br/>
    {% if is_tsumo %}
        親失点: {{mj.cost['main']}} 子失点: {{mj.cost['additional']}}<br />
    {% else %}
        放銃者失点: {{mj.cost['main']}}<br />
    {% endif %} 
    役: 
    {% for yaku in mj.yaku %}
        {{yaku.name}},
    {% endfor %}
    <br/>
    符: 
    {% for fu in mj.fu_details %}
        {{fu['fu']}}({{fu['reason']}}),
    {% endfor %}
    <br/>
    </p>
  </center>
</body>
</html>
```

実行結果

[image: 実行結果]